# Communication to Different Networks

Tags: python, networking, udp

I would like to make a game with python and PyGame where two players play via wi-fi on different networks networks. I currently have this code (which I got from a video).

```
# SERVER

import socket

def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host,port))


    print("Server Started.")
    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print("message From: " + str(addr))
        print("from connected user: " + data)
        data = data.upper()
        print("sending: " + data)
        s.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), addr)
    c.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()

# CLIENT

import socket

def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 5001

    server = ('127.0.0.1',5000)

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host, port))

    message = raw_input("-> ")
    while message != 'q':
        s.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), server)
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print('Received from server: ' + data)
        message = raw_input("-> ")
    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

This works fine on the same machine. How could I make this work on two different computers (on two different LAN)?

Comment: You are going to need to connect to the actual IP addresses instead of the loopback address. If the two networks can communicate, then it should work.

Comment: @RonMaupin, doesn't he also need to `port-forward` ?

Comment: @coder, that depends. There is nothing in the question about NAT. There are many, many networks which don't use NAT.

Comment: @RonMaupin, yes but from his code(`socket.AF_INET`) it seems that he talks about **ipv4**, is it possible for ipv4 not to use NAT?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use IPv4 without NAT. I don't understand why anyone would think otherwise. IPv4 was in production for many years before NAT was proposed. NAT is a kludge meant to help extend the limited IPv4 address space until IPv6 becomes ubiquitous. If you read my comment carefully, I wrote, "_If the two networks can communicate_..."

Answer (score 0):

change to `host= '0.0.0.0'` (for the server)

this makes it publish to any available interface ... if you have a router you (probably) will also need to use the port-forward settings of your router to direct traffic to the correct computer

as an aside ... what is this nonsense? `server = ('127.0.0.1',5000)`

for the client ... just set the public facing IP address of your network with the appropriate port(if you are using portforwarding) ... you canfind this ip address @ http://whatismyip.com

Comment: When I change the server to my public IP address, nothing happens if I try to send data. If I try the same thing on a different device (still on the same network), I get: 
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused.